# In Perl scripts, should we use shell commands or call Perl functions that imitate shell operations?

Tags: perl, shell

I want to know about the best practices here. Suppose I want to get the content of some line of a file. I can use a one-line shell command to get my answer, or write a subroutine, as shown in the code below.

A text file named `some_text`:

```
She laughed. Then both continued eating in silence, like strangers,
but after dinner they walked side by side; and there sprang up
between them the light jesting conversation of people who are free
and satisfied, to whom it does not matter where they go or what
they talk about.
```

Code to get content of line 5 of the file

```
#!perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $file = "some_text";
my $lnum = 5;
my $shellcmd = "awk 'NR==$lnum' $file";
print qx($shellcmd);
print getSrcLine($file, $lnum);

sub getSrcLine {
    my($file, $lnum) = @_;
    open FILE, $file or die "$!";
    my @ray = <FILE>;
    return $ray[$lnum-1];
}
```

I ask this because I see a lot of Perl scripts where at some point, a shell command was called, while at some later point, the same task was done by a call to a (library or handwritten) function, for example, `rm -rf` versus `File::Path::rmtree`. I just want to make it consistent.

What is the recommended thing to do?

Comment: Recomended way depends on the intention of the code.If u want to execute on Non unix machine then go with perl libraries else look at the link i have posted..Hope this helps..

Comment: Maybe each of the scripts was developed over a period of time, possibly by multiple programmers.  The scripts evolved, and the code is not 100% self-consistent, depending in part on how those involved had more or less experience with Perl and shell.

Comment: Note that while slurping an entire 5-line file to get the fifth line is not too painful, it is probably a sub-optimal strategy for getting the fifth line of a million-line file.

Comment: Also, although it doesn't matter much in this example, the `FILE` is not automatically closed on exit from the function because it is not a lexically scoped (`my`) file handle.  I suggest using `open my $FILE, '<', "$file" or die "$!";`, and `my @ray = <$FILE>;`.  Such files are closed when the function terminates.  You can demonstrate that the `FILE` is not closed by adding `seek(FILE, 0, 0) or die "$!";` after the call to `getSrcLine`; it does not generate an error.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks for the insight. I always assumed file handles were closed once you left the function scope. Regarding my other question, based on the comments and responses, I guess it really boils down to personal choice, if portability is not an issue. For me, shell commands are faster to write, so I have a tendency to use them a lot in my Perl scripts.

Comment: Unos, Only lexical file handles are closed automatically. The ones that start with $ and are declared within the scope. See also http://szabgab.com/open-files-in-the-old-way.html Regardless of that @ray = <$fh> will read in the whole file. while (my $line = <$fh>) { } reads line-by-line.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If there's a Perl function for the operation, Perl thinks you should use its version. However, you give an example of a Perl *module* providing a pure Perl way to do it. That's much different. There's no single answer (as in most things), so you have to decide for yourself what to do:

- Does the pure Perl approach do it correctly? For example, [File::Copy](https://www.metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3aCopy) has some limitations because it makes some awkward decisions for the user, so many people think it's broken. See, for instance, [File::Copy versus cp/mv](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=295656).
- Does pure Perl approach do it in an acceptable time? Sometimes the external program is orders of magnitude faster. Sometimes it's a lot slower.
- External commands usually are portable within a family of systems (e.g. all linux-like systems) but probably not across families (e.g. Windows and linux). Your tolerance for that might affect your answer. Even if you think you are running the same command, the different flavors of unix-like systems might have different switches for the operations.
- Passing complicated arguments—spaces, quotes, and special characters—to external commands can make you cry. You have to do a lot of fiddly work to make sure you're handling arguments correctly. Perl subroutines don't care though.
- You have to pay much more attention to what you are doing when you are using the external command. If you just call `rm`, Perl is going to search through your `PATH` and use the first thing called `rm`. That doesn't mean it's the program you think it is. I write about this quite a bit in the "Secure Programming Techniques" in *Mastering Perl*.
- If the pure Perl approach requires a module, especially if that module has many complicated dependencies, you might be in for dependency or distribution hell down the road.

Personally, I start with the pure Perl approach until it doesn't work for the situation.

For your particular examples, I'd use Perl. Shelling out to awk, which is a proto-Perl, is just odd. You should be able to do everything awk does right it Perl. If you have an awk program, you can convert it to Perl with the *a2p* program:

```
 NR==5
```

a2p turns that into (modulo some setup bits at the start):

```
while (<>) {
    print $_ if $. == 5;
}
```

Notice that it still scans the entire file even though you have the fifth line. However, you can use the translated program as a start:

```
while (<>) {
    if( $. == 5 ) {
        print;
        last;
        }
}
```

I don't think you should shell out to some other program to avoid that Perl code.

To remove a directory tree, I like [File::Path](https://www.metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3aPath). It has some dependencies, but they are all in the Perl Standard Library. There's very little pain, if any, associated with that module. I'd use it until I ran into a problem where it didn't work.

Comment: thank you for a detailed answer. I liked the point about security in particular, as I don't consider it a lot while coding in Perl. Also, I met the a2p program, which is really handy! I am convinced now that I should try to avoid external shell commands in my scripts as long as Perl can do the same thing reliably.

Comment: Excellent answer.  The only addition I would make is regarding the script's requirements.  If you're writing a one-time use program, shelling out to a *nix command is quite reasonable if it saves you any time.  I did this recently on a data mangle script for a Datbase export-to-import script.  It was faster to shell out to an external command for part of it, and the script would be thrown away after it ran (correctly) once.  If I were writing a program that would do a similar function every week, I'd have taken the time to implement it properly in Perl, if I could.

Answer (score 4):

If you want your app to be portable to non-unix systems, then definitely code everything in Perl.

If not, it's really up to you... creating a new process is slower, but if it's not important for the task then it doesn't matter. Personally I would pick the solution which I can quicker implement.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that code that works should be the first priority. Yours fails if the file name has a space in it, for example.

Using the shell makes it harder to code correctly since your program needs to properly generate another program to be run by `sh`. (This problem goes away if you use the multi-arg version of system to avoid the shell.)

Furthermore, using external tools can make it hard to handle errors. You didn't even attempt to do so!

On the flip side, there are multiple reasons for using external tools. For example, Perl doesn't provide as good an file copy utility as `cp`; using the `sort` tool allows you to sort arbitrary large files with limited RAM; etc.